# Use ajax response as audio source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to utilize ajax response as html5 audio source.

```
$.post( 
               'getresponse.php',
                {body: '<div><p>Hello, this is testing</p></div>'},
                function (data) {
                    $('#polly-player').attr('src', data);
                    var audio = $('#player')[0];
                    audio.play();
                })
            });
```

But as response data is string it doesn't seem to work. I am sending certain text to server (php) where text gets converted to mp3 response. 
When I do ajax post and get response, it is text:

```
Cache-Control:             no-cache, private
Content-Length:            7533
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type:              audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3
Date:                      Wed, 19 Jul 2017 17:04:26 GMT
X-Pad:                     avoid browser bug

ID3#TSSELavf57.56.101��H�9�"O`...
....
....U"
```

Is there any way I can use it? Please advice.

Thanks,

CIsSharp

Comment: May I ask why you don't set the URL of your Ajax request directly as the src of <video>?

Comment: I am converting the posted text to mp3. So I must use post first. :(

Comment: Just a thought....create new Blob(data)...URL.createObjectUrl from your Blob...and finally set this as src

Comment: To follow on from @mr.alex, you can use the URL directly in the `audio` element as you're returning an `audio/mpeg` content type. You just need to URL encode the `body` value, like this: `<audio autoplay><source src="getresponse.php?body=%3Cdiv%3E%3Cp%3EHello%2C%20this%20is%20testing%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E" /></audio>`

Comment: HI Rory: I cannot use get request because body can be of any length. That's the reason I am trying to achieve it using POST.
@mr.alex: Do you mind sharing code if you have on using Blob?